# Закрытие популярного вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия, дубликаты

Закрыли популярный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1070324/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-put-%D0%B8-patch-%D0%B2-rest) как дубликат. При этом оригинал менее популярен. Кажется, что это противоречит логике. Да и ранее где-то этот вопрос обсуждался уже. Закрывается менее популярный.

Comment: По упомянутому вопросу можно поставить тревогу, чтобы модератор изменил направление дубликата.

Comment: написал просьбу изменить направление дубликата